# JavaScript ES6: How to Iterate Over Object with [Symbol()] names

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to iterate over an object that is using Symbol names to uniquely identify properties. For instance, if I have this object:

```
   const bowl1 = {
     'apple': { color: 'red', weight: 136.078 },
     'banana': { color: 'yellow', weight: 183.151 },
     'orange': { color: 'orange', weight: 170.097 },
     'peach': { color: 'yellow', weight: 176.845 }
   };

   for (var fruit in bowl1) {
       var item = bowl1[fruit];
       console.log(`${fruit}: `, item);
   }

   OUTPUT:
   apple:  { color: 'red', weight: 136.078 }
   banana:  { color: 'yellow', weight: 183.151 }
   orange:  { color: 'orange', weight: 170.097 }
   peach:  { color: 'yellow', weight: 176.845 }

   // can even write your own iterator to get the same results
   function* iterate_object(o) {
      var keys = Object.keys(o);
      for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
         yield [keys[i], o[keys[i]]];
      }
   }

   // output is the same as above
   for (var [key, val] of iterate_object(bowl1)) {
      console.log(key, val);
   }
```

However, if I change this object to use Symbols as such:

```
   const bowl = {
     [Symbol('apple')]: { color: 'red', weight: 136.078 },
     [Symbol('banana')]: { color: 'yellow', weight: 183.15 },
     [Symbol('orange')]: { color: 'orange', weight: 170.097 },
     [Symbol('banana')]: { color: 'yellow', weight: 176.845 }
   };
```

*Note that symbols are used to keep the second banana from overwriting the first.*

Anyway, neither method used above will iterate properly over this object.

Is there a way to iterate over objects using Symbol names?
Does it need to be created as a class and have an iterator method?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Having "second banana" in the object looks like a misuse of Object. You'd better use Array of objects to aviod confusion of the object properties.

Comment: Maybe, it came from an example to illustrate the use of Symbol names so it may not represent the best use of them. I was trying to figure out how to iterate over an object that uses them.

Comment: @SteveIsenberg If you simply wanted to know how to iterate over an object using symbols the documentation has examples of that [**Symbols Examples**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#Examples) - it also mentions the use of `getOwnPropertySymbols` in that example - `Object.getOwnPropertyNames() will not return symbol object properties, however, you can use Object.getOwnPropertySymbols() to get these.`

Comment: Actually you iterate over Array of the object keys, not object. More interesting question is Which "banana" do you get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't get symbol property names because they're not stored as typical character/string values, but you can iterate over the list returned by `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` and use those to pull information out of an Object.

```js
const bowl = {
     [Symbol('apple')]: { color: 'red', weight: 136.078 },
     [Symbol('banana')]: { color: 'yellow', weight: 183.15 },
     [Symbol('orange')]: { color: 'orange', weight: 170.097 },
     [Symbol('banana')]: { color: 'yellow', weight: 176.845 }
   };
   
for(let sym of Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(bowl) ) {
   console.log(bowl[sym]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated above you cannot get the symbol property names because they are not stored as typical character strings. However, the MDN site does say “In addition, Object.getOwnPropertyNames() will not return symbol object properties, however, you can use Object.getOwnPropertySymbols() to get these.”

As such, on order to get information about the objects use Object.getOwnPropertySymbols:

```
for(let sym of Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(bowl) ) {
    console.log(sym, bowl[sym]);
   }
```

OUTPUT:

```
   Symbol(apple) { color: 'red', weight: 136.18 }
   Symbol(banana) { color: 'yellow', weight: 183.15 }
   Symbol(orange) { color: 'orange', weight: 170.97 }
   Symbol(banana) { color: 'yellow', weight: 176.84 }
```

As you can see you don’t get the symbol names as strings, but it will return the symbol and their referenced objects.

You have to do some extra work if you want to convert the symbol to a string and just see the property name.

```
for(let sym of Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(bowl) ) {
      // remove the 'Symbol (' from string
      let symStr = String(sym).substring(7);

      // now lop off the last char ')'
      symStr = symStr.slice(0, -1);

      console.log(symStr, bowl[sym]);
   }
```

OUTPUT:

```
   apple { color: 'red', weight: 136.18 }
   banana { color: 'yellow', weight: 183.15 }
   orange { color: 'orange', weight: 170.97 }
   banana { color: 'yellow', weight: 176.84 }
```

You can combine the string functions on one line if you want.

```
let symStr = String(sym).substring(7).slice(0, -1);
```

Maybe not the best use for Symbols and there are both global and local symbols. The example used above and this is from lesson material are local.

Answer (score 1):

Acutally there are two methods, will share it for your reference,

```
const bowl = {
[Symbol('apple')]: { color: 'red', weight: 136.078 },
[Symbol('banana')]: { color: 'yellow', weight: 183.151 },
[Symbol('orange')]: { color: 'orange', weight: 170.097 },
[Symbol('banana')]: { color: 'yellow', weight: 176.845 }
};

const bowlReflect = Reflect.ownKeys(bowl);
const ownPropertySymbols = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(bowl);

**Method:1**
for(const fruit of bowlReflect){
 console.log(bowl[fruit])
 }

Method:2
for(const fruit of ownPropertySymbols){
 console.log(bowl[fruit])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fantasma = Symbol('fantasma');
console.log(fantasma);
// Symbol(fantasma)

const objetoLiteral = {
// propiedad: valor,
  [fantasma]: '', // Symbol()
  uno: 1,
  dos: 2,
  tres: 3,
};
console.log(objetoLiteral);
/*
{
  uno: 1,
  dos: 2,
  tres: 3,
  [Symbol(fantasma)]: ''
}
*/

Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(objetoLiteral).map((propiedad) => {
  const valor = objetoLiteral[propiedad];
  console.log(propiedad, '➜', valor);
});
// Symbol(fantasma) ➜
```

Comment: When commenting on a possible new solution that already has an accepted answer from a few years ago, it would help if you provided more context on how this would be better. It would also be helpful if you would explain your answer, how does it work, why does it work like it works, and what does it do what other answers don't.